# Unit Testing Oracle views

Tags: java, sql, oracle, unit-testing, automated-tests

I've searched for best practices, tools and libraries to test oracle db views, but did not find much. Some SQL editors have their own built-in ways, there are some libraries for SQL Server and there's http://utplsql.org/ for PL/SQL, which seems to be the closest thing, but I'm not sure if it fits my needs.

Problem statement: we have tons of business logic written as SQL views. Over time this has become very hard to maintain and small changes can cause surprising regressions. (for all the usual reasons).

I would like something that integrates with a standard java build pipeline so that when we deploy any changes to the db objects (which we currently do with liquibase) we can run a full test suite and reduce the risk of regressions.

If a java solution is not possible, then a SQL or PL/SQL one might also be OK.

The first naïve approach I could think of would be something that

1. creates some test tables with test data
2. mocks the view that needs to be tested, by replacing the source tables with the test ones
3. runs a "select *" from the view and compares it with the desired output
4. drops the test tables and the mocked view

Is there any existing tool/library that does the above?
If not, is there any particular reason why the above approach would not work?

Thanks

Comment: Test the queries first.  Then create the views.

Comment: How do you programmatically test the queries to check for regressions? What do you do with existing views?

Comment: You set up a development environment that has controlled data and you define the views there.  You can then apply regression tests.  I will also point out that this is trickier in SQL than in other languages, because of the dependence on data.

Comment: some views query other views. If we try to set that up we would end up with a name conflict between the test data table and the source views. I can see how a such dev environment would work on a small scale but not in our case. They also query views/tables via dblinks.